# Why HPX requires future's "then" to be part of a DAG (directed acyclic graph)?

Tags: hpx

In HPX introduction tutorials you learn that you can make use of future's `then()` method, that allows you to enqueue some operation to be computed when the future is ready.

In this manual there is a sentence that says ["Used to build up dataflow DAGs (directed acyclic graphs)"](https://stellar-group.github.io/hpx/docs/sphinx/latest/html/quickstart.html#writing-task-based-applications) when explaining how to use thens.

My question is, what does it mean that this queue has to be acyclic? Can I make a function that re-computes a future inside a then? This would look like `myfuture.then( recompute myfuture ; myfuture.then() )` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of a `hpx::future` (very similar, if not identical to `std::experimental::future`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future) is an one-shot pipeline between an anonymous producer and a consumer. It does not represent the task itself but just the produced result (that might not have been computed yet).

Thus 'recomputing' a future (as you put it) can only mean to reinitialize the future from an asynchronous provider (`hpx::async`, `future<>::then`, etc.).

```
hpx::future<int> f = hpx::async([]{ return 42; });

hpx::future<int> f2 = f.then(
    [](hpx::future<int> r) 
    {
        // this is guaranteed not to block as the continuation 
        // will be called only after `f` has become ready (note:
        // `f` has been moved-to `r`)
        int result = r.get();

        // 'reinitialize' the future
        r = hpx::async([]{ return 21; });

        // ...do things with 'r'

        return result;
    });

// f2 now represents the result of executing the chain of the two lambdas
std::cout << f2.get() << '\n';        // prints '42'
```

I'm not sure if this answers your question and why you would like to do that, but here you go.

Comment: If I understand correctly this reinitialization creates a completely new `r` object that has nothing to do with the previous one. While this distinction has no impact here, it may have when you have `hpx::shared_future` with multiple follow-up tasks waiting for it. This reinitialization will _not_ have any impact on those follow-up tasks, they will still see the old value stored (42), even if the hpx scheduler launches those tasks much later. Am I reading this right?